# Calling upon two different files with similar locations

Tags: c++

I have a word counting program and two files to read from. The trial-run text file, "demo.txt", is read using the program and works. After changing the appropriate variable names to "infile.txt", the same program does no work properly with text file "infile.txt".
I simply cntrl+fed, replaced all demo.txt with infile.txt expecting the program to work. Nothing. Upon reverting "infile.txt" to "demo.txt", the program works as expected.
Could similarity in file location be the cause of this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
 
using namespace std;


int main()
{

string line;
string character;
string input;

int words = 0;
int letter1 = 0;
int letter2 = 0;
int letter3 = 0;
int letter4 = 0;
int letter5 = 0;
int letter6 = 0;
int letter7 = 0;
int letter8 = 0;
int letter9 = 0;

ifstream myfile("infile.txt");

cout << "Welcome to the word counter" << endl;

cout << "What file would you like a report on (or type exit to quit): ";
getline(cin, input);

do{
    if (input == "Exit") {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(input != "infile.txt"){
        cout << "Sorry that file cannot be found. Please enter a file you would like a report on (or type exit to quit): ";
        getline(cin, input);
    }
} while (input != "infile.txt");

if (input == "infile.txt") {
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\tuwan\\source\\repos\\Word_Counter_Revision\\infile.txt");
    getline(myfile, line);
    
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            int start = -1;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
                char ch = line[i];
                if (start == -1) {
                    if (!isalpha(ch)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        start = i;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (isalpha(ch)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        int wordLength = i - start;
                        start = -1;

                        switch (wordLength) {
                            case 1:
                                letter1++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                letter2++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                letter3++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                letter4++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                letter5++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                letter6++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                letter7++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                letter8++;
                                words ++;
                                break;
                            default:
                                letter9++;
                                words ++;
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            cout << "-Word Report for " << input << "-" << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "Length:" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << "Count:" << endl;
            cout << setfill('-') << setw(21) << "" << endl;
            cout << setfill(' ');

            cout << setw(10) << left << "1" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter1 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "2" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter2 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "3" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter3 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "4" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter4 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "5" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter5 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "6" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter6 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "7" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter7 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << "8" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter8 << endl;
            cout << setw(10) << left << ">8" << "|";
            cout << setw(10) << right << letter9 << endl;
            cout << "Total words in the file: " << words << endl;

            myfile.close();
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

}

`

```
Output recieved

Welcome to the word counter
What file would you like a report on (or type exit to quit): infile.txt
-Word Report for infile.txt-
Length:   |    Count:
---------------------
1         |         0
2         |         0
3         |         0
4         |         0
5         |         0
6         |         0
7         |         0
8         |         0
>8        |         0
Total words in the file: 0

Expected output
Welcome to the word counter
What file would you like a report on (or type exit to quit): demo.txt
-Word Report for demo.txt-
Length:   |    Count:
---------------------
1         |         2
2         |         3 
3         |         1
4         |         7
5         |         2
6         |         1
7         |         0
8         |         1
>8        |         0
Total words in the file: 17
```

Comment: Please, **learn about arrays**. This is not a sustainable development model. `std::vector<int>` helps here, where if you want it pre-sized to some arbitrary length, `std::vector<int> letters(9, 0)`.

Comment: What the words "does not work" mean? What do you expect, what do you get?